# Magento 2 customer account doesn't allow special characters(å, ä, ø, ö, æ etc.) in the email address

Tags: magento2, email, customer-account, customer-attribute, special-character

Magento 2 customer account doesn't allow special characters`(å, ä, ø, ö, æ etc.)` in the email address field.

Please do needful to allow special characters(å, ä, ø, ö, æ etc.) in the email address field for Magento 2 new customers or edit customers from the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [reference on the Magento 2 Repository in Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8094), you can create a plugin to fix like that:

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Email\Model\Template">
        <plugin name="mail_subject" type="VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin\Template" sortOrder="100" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Template.php**

```
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin;

class Template
{
    public function afterGetSubject(
        \Magento\Email\Model\Template $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return htmlspecialchars_decode((string)$result, ENT_QUOTES);
    }
}
```